# Invalid redirect_uri parameter for Reddit API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, oauth-2.0, reddit

I'm trying to implement oAuth with Reddit using Devise & the omniauth-reddit gem.

It seems to be passing the local url & api key fine.

```
https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?response_type=account&client_id=API_KEY&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fusers%2Fauth%2Freddit%2Fcallback&scope=identity
```

However the response I get is:

```
forbidden (reddit.com)

you are not allowed to do that
— invalid redirect_uri parameter.
```

I've tried setting the redirect_uri to 127.0.0.1:3000 as well as hosted url(heroku), but to no avail.

So now I don't understand if I'm still just giving them the wrong URL or passing a parameter that shouldn't be there.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

OAuth servers (almost always) require that you register the callback address with them. Have you done that? They check that what you send in the `redirect_uri` matches what you entered. In Reddit:

[image]

Just tested it. You have to enter the exact callback URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/auth/reddit/callback`

If you miss one segment, it will report that error.

Comment: Sure, as I pointed out in the question, I`ve tried setting the redirect_uri both to http://127.0.0.1:3000  & http://projectx.com

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. Have you tried with the fully qualified URL? trailing slash? Sometimes servers are picky with the comparison.

Comment: +1 for noting that the site redirecr uri must match what is being sent. I was totally sending my new uri but forgot to update the preferences on reddit.

Comment: I made the mistake of keeping it `http://127.0.0.1` in my app and `http://localhost` in reddit preferences.

Answer (score 5):

Ok. So I just figured out a <s>irritating</s> fun little quirk with the Reddit API:

Turns out, it also returns the `— invalid redirect_uri parameter` error if there's an invalid `client ID`! Clearly, I thought the `client_id` was the same thing as the `secret`

**NOPE**

Instead, it's the easy-to-miss ID that's right below your application name. Once you use the proper ID, everything works . . .

[image: counter-intuitive]

Comment: Note: If you've ever used your "secret" as an ID, your secret may no longer be secret, and you should create an new OAuth2 client to generate a new ID and secret.